# User data null in product page

Tags: opencart-3

This is situation on my Opencart ver 3.0.2, after I login I can go to another page and can see my account at top bar. After that I go to product for see details, and then my account change to Login | Register, when I add to cart items not add to my account. I try debug at controller, insert code `var_dump($this->customer->isLogged());`. But data show `null`.

Comment: When does this situation started? New hosting/server? Some new modules?

Comment: After I change to new hosting.